# Warning: No Previous Declaration - C++

Tags: c++

I am stumped about the cause of this:

```
recorders/r5000device.cpp: In function ‘unsigned int r5000_device_tspacket_handler(unsigned char*, int, void*)’:
recorders/r5000device.cpp:34:14: warning: no previous declaration for ‘unsigned int r5000_device_tspacket_handler(unsigned char*, int, void*)’ [-Wmissing-declarations]
 unsigned int r5000_device_tspacket_handler(unsigned char *tspacket, int len, void *callback_data)
          ^
recorders/r5000device.cpp: In function ‘void r5000_msg(char*)’:
recorders/r5000device.cpp:44:6: warning: no previous declaration for ‘void r5000_msg(char*)’ [-Wmissing-declarations]
 void r5000_msg(char * msg)
  ^
```

Answer (score 11):

You have the compile flag **-Wmissing-declarations** set. The compiler wants to see declarations (prototypes - usually in headers) for all function. Just add the missing headers or declare the prototype at the top of the file.

Comment: I tried (as below), but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Make sure you include the header file. If this function is local to the file, declare it as static. BTW the Intel compiler gives a similar warning

Comment: Thanks egur.  I solved it by putting in r5000device.h: `unsigned int r5000_device_tspacket_handler(unsigned char *tspacket, int len, void *callback_data);
 void r5000_msg(char*);' so you'd nailed it.  It was a big hassle determining whether I needed #ifndef or some other dressing up, but it turns out I just needed the bare declarations.

Comment: can also put the function into anonymous namespace

Answer (score 0):

Free functions in C++ need to be declared in a header file as well as defined in a .cpp file.  [How do you define a global function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874346/how-do-you-define-a-global-function-in-c)

Comment: It doesn't work as your link says it should.  In r5000device.h I put at the top: 
`#ifndef r5000_device_tspacket_handler
#define r5000_device_tspacket_handler
unsigned int r5000_device_tspacket_handler(unsigned char *tspacket, int len, void *callback_data);
#endif`
... but it responds: `In file included from videosource.cpp:39:0:
recorders/r5000device.h:9:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘unsigned’
 unsigned int r5000_device_tspacket_handler(unsigned char *tspacket, int len, void *callback_data);`